# Renaming Row Count Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I can’t find how to rename the row counting column in a table in an SQL Server RDMS. When you create a table and you have user created columns, A and B for example, to the farthest right of those columns, you have the Row Number column.

It does not have a title. It just sequentially counts all the rows in your table. It's default. Is it possible to manipulate this column denoting the row numbers? Meaning, can I rename it, put its contents in descending order, etc. If so, how?

And if not, what are the alternatives to have a sequentially counting column counting all the rows in my table?

Comment: Where is this row counting column of which you speak? Are you talking about the results displayed when you run a query in SSMS?

Comment: You should just create your own column, per Gordon's suggestion below.  Even if you could control the label on the auto generated column, it still would not formally be part of the result set.

Comment: Yes, this works. I’m very new to this. I figured could just give a name to the default column that is generated after I query but the more I say it the sillier it sounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You can create your own column with sequential values using an `identity` column.  This is usually a primary key.

Alternatively, when you query the table, you can assign a sequential number (with no gaps) using `row_number()`.  In general, you want a column that specifies the ordering:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (order by <ordering column>) as my_sequential_column
from t;
```

Comment: Oh ok l see. And yes, sorry I meant when I execute a query. Apologies I’m really new to database development . In university if that helps you understand my level of competence.